# Plot 3D graph of the results from finite element method

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I use the finite element method in 2D and get the following function

P(x,y,k), where x = 1:101, y = 1:101, k = 1:2001.

To each discrete time k, I want to plot a 3D graph (x,y,P) so I use the following codes:

For example, for k = 3

```
  P = zeros(numx,numy,numt);

  for k=1:numt
  for i=2:numx-1
      for j=2:numy-1
          P(i,j,k+1) = P(i,j,k) + 1*(dt/dx^2)*( P(i+1,j,k) - 2*P(i,j,k) + P   (i-1,j,k) ) + 1*(dt/dy^2)*( P(i,j+1,k) - 2*P(i,j,k) + P(i,j-1,k) ); 
      end
  end
  end

  figure(1)
  xx = 1:100;
  yy = 1:100;
  [XX,YY] = meshgrid(xx,yy)
  PP = eval(P(XX,YY,3));
  surf(XX,YY,PP)
```

However, the matlab says: "Undefined function 'eval' for input arguments of
type 'double'."

How do I fix it and plot the 3D graph?

Comment: Does `P` take matricies as an input (and return a matrix of the same size)? In which case you should be able to use `PP=P(XX,YY,3)`. Otherwise if `P` takes and returns only scalars, you might need to loop through the entries or use [`arrayfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html).

Comment: @Steve Actually P is a <101x101x2002 double>

Comment: In that case `PP=P(xx,yy,3)` should do the trick (small `x` and `y`), or even just `surf(PP(:,:,3))` since your `xx` and `yy` are taking integer values.

Comment: See [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). Also don't expect anything exciting from your code, the solution is going to be zero for all time (you seem to be trying to solve `p_t = 2*p_{xx}` with no zero boundary and initial conditions.

Comment: @Steve I am trying to solve 2D diffusion equation. Yes, it is all zero and am figuring out why.

Comment: Because 0 is a (trivial) solution to your equation. Maybe try it with some other initial condition.